# ColdFusion 2018 GETSUPPORTEDTAGATTRIBUTES and method was not found errors when starting application

Tags: coldfusion

About an hour ago our production server (ACF2018HF15) hit 100% CPU usage, so I remoted in and stopped/started the process and it appeared to come back up.  Our main site and one other site are giving these errors in the application log:

> cfbase2ecfc2027200501$funcGETSUPPORTEDTAGATTRIBUTES The specific sequence of files included or processed is: E:\WebSites\site1\index.cfm, line: 70 "

One other website - \site2\ is showing the same error, same line number (even though they are completely different sites).
Now a 3rd site is logging this error:

> The keyExists method was not found.Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types or the keyExists method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0 methods that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java object and you verified that the method exists, use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: E:\WebSites\site3\index.cfm, line: 41"

We've rebooted (no change).  We've tried to step through Application.cfc but because this is happening to different sites I fear this is some lower level CF issue.

Answer (score 4):

While we have no identified the cause of the CPU usage spike to 100%, the solution for this issue was to stop the ColdFusion service, navigate to \cfusion\wwwroot\web-inf\ and rename (or delete) the cfclasses folder.  Restart the service and let CF recreate it and begin to compile the class files.  (the reason we chose to rename was it was quicker than trying to delete 74,000 .class files).

Comment: One way that I've experienced CPU spikes was by looping through large amounts of data.  Having a query in that loop makes it even more likely.

Comment: @DanBracuk - we tracked it down to a search function that a new employee was using.  I didn't even realize it was there and it worked fine when we had 50,000 rows, now at 5M trying to search a blob for encrypted data brought it to it's knees.  The solution will be to have the search look in an indexed hashed column of the data for a match.